# Preserving entity references when transforming XSLT with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'd like to transform some XSLT-files with XSLT to get new XSLT-files, which is actually working quite fine. Only one function is providing problems: If I copy / or even if I try to build this function manually

```
   <xsl:function name="mr:get_xmlname">
    <xsl:param name="name"/>

    <xsl:value-of 
        select="replace($name,'[^A-Z|_|a-z|&#xC0;-&#xD6;|&#xD8;-&#xF6;|&#xF8;-&#x2FF;|&#x370;-&#x37D;|&#x37F;-&#x1FFF;|&#x200C;-&#x200D;|&#x2070;-&#x218F;|&#x2C00;-&#x2FEF;|&#x3001;-&#xD7FF;|&#xF900;-&#xFDCF;|&#xFDF0;-&#xFFFD;|&#x10000;-&#xEFFFF;|\-|\.|0-9|&#xB7;|&#x0300;-&#x036F;|&#x203F;-&#x2040;]','_')"
    />
</xsl:function>
```

I always end up getting

```
    <xsl:function name="mr:get_xmlname">
    <xsl:param name="name"/>
    <xsl:value-of
        select="replace($name,'[^A-Z|_|a-z|À-Ö|Ø-ö|ø-˿|Ͱ-ͽ|Ϳ-῿|‌-‍|⁰-↏|Ⰰ-⿯|、-퟿|豈-﷏|ﷰ-�|-|\-|\.|0-9|·|̀-ͯ|‿-⁀]','_')"
    />
</xsl:function>
```

But actually I want it to remain as it was before. I already tried some things using disable-output-escaping but it seems to have no impact like it's an attribute and no text node.

If you would have some ideas how I could build the statement "manually" it would also be a working solution for me.

Thanks a lot in advance

martre

Comment: I don't think there is a way to preserve character references in an XML input document. If you want to ensure those characters are serialized as character references in the result of an XSLT transformation you would need to define a character map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `<xsl:output encoding="us-ascii"/>`, which will force all non-ASCII characters to be serialized using hex or decimal character references, whether they started life that way or not.

Comment: thank you a lot for this quick help, "Windows-1252" was the encoding output that finally solved the problem, as there were some non-ascii characters within some comments